# How to use the index in an enumerate for loop with if statement (python)

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, enumerate

I have a nested dictionary, of which it is possible to access a value like this:

`print(list['sublist'][0]['item'][0]['commentId'])`

However if I create a for loop and would like to use the index like this it gives me a keyerror:

```
    for index,sublist in enumerate(list['sublist']):
        if sublist[index]['item'][0]['commentId'] == commentid:
            number = sublist[index]['item'][0]['positionId']
            username = sublist[index]['subListCreator']
    print(number)
    print(username)
```

The error:

```
, in send_async_notification
    if sublist[index]['item'][0]['commentId'] == commentid:
  File "/Users/ ...... /venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mongoengine/base/document.py", line 263, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(name)
```

The whole goal of this exercise is to get two particular values in a nested array based on a deeper nested commentId. If there is a match, I would like to know the positionId and the subListCreator underneath it. An item can only have one commentId, hence the [0] in the code.

It would also be ok to just have the whole dictionary "branch" that matches the commentId, this would also make things work.

Btw, `print(commentid)` gives me the commentid I would like to match against. Just to explain its present.

Hope there's a solution here, wonder why it's not working. Looking forward to any answer!

Comment: Why do you keep referencing `sublist[index]` if what you really want to access is `sublist[0]`?

Comment: The right commentid might be in the first, or second etc. iteration of the sublist. [0] would give the right answer in some cases, but not in all.

Comment: But `index` is the index of `sublist` in `list['sublist']` - if you want to enumerate all the items _in_ the given `sublist` then you'll need another `for` loop (or a list comprehension)

Comment: Would it be possible to still access the parent value sublist['subListCreator'] in those cases? (I think I tried, but doubting myself now :))

Comment: Given that I have no idea what your data structure looks like, maybe? :) Please update your question and describe how the list is constructed (code is better than prose)

Comment: just tried, I mixed up things, thanks a lot for commenting, this helped me out! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mathias for commenting! A double for-loop solves my problem:

```
    for sublist in list['sublist']:
        for item in sublist['item']:
            if item['commentId'] == commentid:
                number = item['positionId']
                username = sublist['subListCreator']
```